# How to extract string after a marker?

Tags: c#, querying

I'm working on a project to perform a `query` into a `set of files` where the `query criteria` are inputted by a `user`.

Essentially, if the user inputs:

**/T"some text"**

The query will look for any file that contains "some text."

If a user inputs:

**/T"some text" /T"some other text"**

The query will look for a file that contains both or at least one such criteria.

I have a couple of ideas about how to perform the query itself, but my question is how can I `extract the text` after the `/T` and in-between `the quotes`. I plan on putting the extracted string into some data structure.

I saw some examples of using IndexOf and such, but they would essentially look for the first instance of `/T` and extract everything else after that. Is there a method that would allow a `bounded way` of getting this information, whether it is some class or `implementation of regex`?

Comment: Appreciate your findings and ideas, proceed with them and come back if you are facing any specific issues/errors in implementation. Try to do it yourself don't expect capsule snippets

Comment: Would String.Split on /T work for you to get an array of strings?

Comment: can the text itself contain quotation marks? If so, how would you escape them? You might consider using regex if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = "/T\"some text\" /T\"some other text\"";
var criterias = input.Split(new[] { "/T\"", "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                     .ToList();
```